# SVG Fill and Filter urls from css not working on safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, svg-filters

I created an animation for my personal website, its working in Chrome and Firefox with no problems and I don't care about IE, but its not working on Safari, I think because Safari won't recognise the fill:url(..) and filter:url(..) from seperate css file. Here's the actual animation link from codepen: http://codepen.io/GetTurnt/pen/kXREWw I would really like to know what is happening.

Here is the actual code:

```css
    .container {
      width:50%;
      height:50%;
      padding: 0 25%;
    }
    
    .st0 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-width:31;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:228.0897;
      opacity:0.9;
      stroke-dashoffset: -228.0897;
      animation-name: line1;
      animation-duration: .25s;
      animation-delay: 3s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes line1 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -228.0897;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
      }
      80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -30;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: -15;
      }
      100%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st1 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-width:31;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:191.6966;
      opacity:0.9;
      stroke-dashoffset: 191.6966;
      animation-name: line2;
      animation-duration: .25s;
      animation-delay: 3s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes line2 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 191.6966;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 50;
      }
      80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 30;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 15;
      }
      100%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st2 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-width:31;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:228.2286;
      opacity:0.9;
      stroke-dashoffset: 228.2286;
      animation-name: line3;
      animation-duration: .25s;
      animation-delay: 3s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes line3 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 228.2286;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 50;
      }
      80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 30;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 15;
      }
      100%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st3 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-width:31;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:228.2286;
      opacity:0.9;
      stroke-dashoffset: 228.2286;
      animation-name: line4;
      animation-duration: .25s;
      animation-delay: 3s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes line4 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 228.2286;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 50;
      }
      80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 30;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 15;
      }
      100%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st4 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:411;
      stroke-dashoffset:411;
      filter:url(#dropshadow);
      animation-name: m;
      animation-duration: .75s;
      animation-delay: 2.5s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes m {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 411;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
      100%{
        fill:url(#SVGID_1_);
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st5 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:162;
      stroke-dashoffset:162;
      filter:url(#dropshadow);
      animation-name: p1;
      animation-duration: .5s;
      animation-delay: 2.5s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes p1 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 162;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
      100%{
        fill:url(#SVGID_2_);
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st6 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:161;
      stroke-dashoffset:161;
      filter:url(#dropshadow);
      animation-name: p2;
      animation-duration: .5s;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes p2 {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 161;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
      100%{
        fill:url(#SVGID_3_);
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .st7 {
      fill:none;
      stroke:#E27A4D;
      stroke-miterlimit:10;
      stroke-dasharray:381;
      stroke-dashoffset:381;
      filter:url(#dropshadow);
      animation-name: c;
      animation-duration: .75s;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes c {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 381;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 1;
      }
      90%{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
      100%{
        fill:url(#SVGID_4_);
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 305.7 217.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 305.7 217.6;" xml:space="preserve">
    
    <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="62.4629" cy="34.0002" r="39.9731" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#383D48"/>
     <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#23262D"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="147.3418" cy="93.7559" r="20.996" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#383D48"/>
     <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#23262D"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="SVGID_3_" cx="152.9411" cy="99.3551" r="20.885" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#383D48"/>
     <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#23262D"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="SVGID_4_" cx="243.2371" cy="159" r="39.9731" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
     <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#383D48"/>
     <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#23262D"/>
    </radialGradient>
    
                <defs>
                 <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
                  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
                  <feOffset dx="0" dy="7" result="offsetblur"/>
                  <feComponentTransfer>
                  <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.35"/>
                  </feComponentTransfer>
                  <feMerge>
                  <feMergeNode/>
                  <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
                  </feMerge>
                 </filter>
                </defs>
     
      
     
    <line class="st0" x1="96.5" y1="34" x2="288.4" y2="34"/>
    <line class="st1" x1="17.3" y1="96.5" x2="152.8" y2="96.5"/>
    <line class="st2" x1="288.4" y1="96.5" x2="152.8" y2="96.5"/>
    <line class="st3" x1="17.3" y1="159" x2="209.4" y2="159"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M17.3,0l45.2,31l45.2-31v68H87.1V36.8L62.5,54.9L37.8,36.8V68H17.3V0z"/>
    <g>
     <polygon class="st5" points="131.3,114.8 136.4,109.7 134.4,107.7 161.3,80.8 163.3,82.8 168.3,77.7 163.4,72.8 150.1,86.1 
      136.8,72.8 126.3,83.3 139.6,96.5 126.3,109.8  "/>
     <polygon class="st6" points="160.5,96.5 173.8,83.2 169.1,78.5 164,83.5 165.8,85.3 138.9,112.2 137.1,110.4 132.1,115.5 
      136.8,120.2 150.1,107 163.3,120.2 173.8,109.8  "/>
    </g>
    <path class="st7" d="M288.4,185.3c-9.4,4.8-21.7,7.7-35.7,7.7c-32.5,0-54.6-14.6-54.6-34s22.1-34,54.6-34c14,0,26.3,2.8,35.7,7.7
     l-9.9,15c-6.9-3.1-16.3-5.2-25.8-5.2c-16.3,0-30,6.2-30,16.6c0,10.4,13.7,16.6,30,16.6c9.5,0,18.9-2.1,25.8-5.2L288.4,185.3z"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Note that I have tried using `fill:url('#hash')` , `fill:url('/#hash')` and moved the radialGradient into the `<defs>` tag to no avail, it isn't working. I hope that it's a simple mistake I've made.

Comment: what version of safari - & iOS or MacOS?

Comment: OS X 9.1.2, currently don't have an iOS device at hand

Comment: If your css is in an external file, that should not work in FF either, url(#id) points to yourfile.css#id which doesn't exists. Chrome is buggy here... but if you say it works in FF, then your css might not be external and maybe it's just that safari doesn't support filter declaration from css, or at least it needs to be prefixed ?

Comment: filter needs to be prefixed for safari

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not urls to fills and filters it was the `fill:none`, I had to use `fill: ('#..')` and `fill-opacity:0.01` and alter fill-opacity to 1 during keyframes, its a little bit buggy but it gets the job done for the time being, if anybody has another solution, please do share.

Comment: ..and moving styles inline into the svg/html completely solved my problem

Comment: Mete, can you share the inline solution?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and yes the problem is the `fill:none`, but I solved using `fill: transparent`